# Rhino Mocks Last Call Return an IList?

Tags: mocking, rhino-mocks

When using Rhino mocks is it possible to make it return a new List

```
        MockRepository mock = new MockRepository();
        IPersonRepository person = mock.Stub<IPersonRepository>();
        using(mock.Record())
        {
            person.GetPersonByFKId(1);
            IList<Person> people= new List<Person>();
            people.Add(new Person(100, "Ted", 200));
            LastCall.Return(people); 

        }
        Address add = new Address (person);
        person.GetPeopleWithAddressField("Ted");//FAIL it will try to ref people
        //list and it is always null
```

Is the Syntax above valid? I have tried it with both Stub and Dynamic Mock and people is always null. Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can return a new List.   It would be easier to use the AAA syntax though:

```
IPersonRepository person = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IPersonRepository>();
IList<Person> people = new List<Person>();
people.Add(new Person(100, "Ted", 200));
person.Stub(p => p.GetPersonByFKId(1)).Return(people);
```